# Jooq whether there are plugins like mybatis page

Tags: jooq

I used jooq when found no similar to mybatis page plugin or similar spring data pa paging. Will jooq have it? If not, then trouble giving a good solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jOOQ supports SQL style offset pagination through `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` as documented in the manual here:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause

Alternatively, you might also want to look at jOOQ's built-in keyset pagination support, which is often the better choice:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/seek-clause/
- https://blog.jooq.org/2016/08/10/why-most-programmers-get-pagination-wrong/